# Unbiased estimator of variance for samples *without* replacement

Tags: estimation, variance, sampling, unbiased-estimator

This is a follow-up question on that one:
 [Could Bessel's correction make sample variance estimation even more biased?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70086/could-bessels-correction-make-sample-variance-estimation-even-more-biased)

I understand that you need Bessel's correction to get an unbiased estimate of variance in case you sample *with* replacement. Now in practice most sampling is done *without* replacement (e.g. asking voters about their preferences or studying the effects of new drugs).

My questions are:
- What is the unbiased estimator for variance in cases of samples *without* replacement?
- Choosing only between the classical estimators for *population variance* and *sample variance* wouldn't it be better in most cases to take the *population variance* for samples because it is less biased than *sample variance* in cases of samples *without* replacement?

Comment: It is erroneous to assume the population variance would be less biased than the sample variance, because the bias in the former (for samples with replacement) is of order $1/n$ for *sample* sizes of $n$ whereas the difference between sampling with and without replacement introduces errors only of size $1/(N-n)$ where $N$ is the *population* size which ordinarily is hugely greater than $n$. Moreover, in the case of studying drug effects there is no definite value of $N$ because we wish to extend inference even to future populations, so $N$ is effectively infinite.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're trying to estimate the population variance, σ², then the population variance is a perfect estimator of the population variance.  I suspect that is not what you meant.  Let's call Σ(x - x̄)²/n the maximum-likelihood estimator of σ².

Yes, when sampling without replacement from a finite population, s² tends to overestimate the true variance, σ², and using the maximum-likelihood estimator gives you a lower estimate than s².  But doing so might over-correct or under-correct.  There would still be a bias.

If you multiply s² by the factor (N-1)/N, where N is the size of the finite population, you will get an unbiased estimator of σ².